# accessing current element index and modify corresponding text javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck on this and basically I have multiple select options and text beside and I want to modify the current value of the text of each of the select elements.

I hope you'll have ample time to see if this can be done or am I approaching this differently. (fyi: my current script is a work in progress php post which sends these elements as an array but would want to tinker on javascript for better user experience)

```
<script>
  function stValue(idx) {
  alert(idx);
  }
</script>

<select name="vopt[]" id="vopt[]" onchange="stValue(this.prototype.indexOf());">
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<p id="vch[]" name="vch[]">[value here]</p>
<select name="vopt[]" id="vopt[]" onchange="stValue(this.prototype.indexOf());">
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<p id="vch[]" name="vch[]">[value here]</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49t9Lj0d/

Comment: Your HTML has a few invalid attributes. `name` isn't valid on a `<p>` tag, and each `id` needs to be unique.

Comment: does this mean I can't implement this kind of approach? i mean using array as element id? (with the exception on anomaly on this <p> tag), but how come I can successfully pass it as a valid $_POST on PHP?

Comment: The `name` will be used in the POST, so it's fine for submitting to PHP. But just for having valid HTML, the `id` needs to be unique for the sake of fetching elements from JavaScript without ambiguity. The `id` and `name` don't have to be the same. It's okay for `name` to be duplicated, but `id` shouldn't.

Comment: thanks for your clarification, do you have any suggestion how to achieve this function? Just for better clarity, I am generating these select tags dynamically based from the number of records from a fetched data, wherein if i have 4 records, I will have 4 select tags, and I prefer to create reusable javascript code for simplicity. thanks for your time.

Comment: can you use jquery?

Comment: maybe? I'm really a newbie on javascript but have enough strong knowledge to debug and use codes based on available syntax on stackoverflow and other resources, can you suggest any jQuery approach on my problem? thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Changes

- Replaced all `<p>` with `<output>`.
- Wrapped everything in a `<fieldset>`.
- Added one eventListener on the `<fieldset>`.
- Removed inline event handlers on the selects.
- Details of how a single eventListener replaces three inline event handlers are in the comments of the source.

#### SNIPPET

```js
// Reference the parent of selects (i.e. <fieldset>).

var set = document.querySelector('fieldset');

/*
Listen for a change event on any form
element under <fieldset> (i.e. <select>).
*/

set.addEventListener('change', setValue, false);

/*
Event handler will determine exactly which select
was selected by using e.target property.

After the selected <select> is referenced, the
active <option>'s text is retrieved using bracket
notation and the selectedIndex property.

Next, the method nextSibling is used to locate
the closest <output>

textContent is used to place the value in the
<output>

e.stopPropagation(); is to prevent any unnecessary
event bubbling.
*/

function setValue(e) {
  if (e.target != e.currentTarget) {
    var selected = e.target.id;
    var sel = document.getElementById(selected);
    var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    var target = sel.nextSibling;
    target.textContent = text;
  }
  e.stopPropagation();

}
```

```css
select {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    vOpt vCh
  </legend>

  <select id="vopt1" name="vopt1">
    <option>----</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <output id="vch1" name="vch1"></output>

  <select id="vopt2" name="vopt2">
    <option>----</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <output id="vch2" name="vch2"></output>

  <select id="vopt3" name="vopt3">
    <option>----</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <output id="vch3" name="vch3"></output>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: thanks mate! this is as near as I want, although my only issue is my existing $_POST variable since I wanted it to be as neat as possible and be passed as an array, thank you for your time! this is definitely a big help!

Comment: You are very welcome sir. Did you need an array of all results? `var list = document.querySelectorAll('output');`  `var arr=Array.prototype.slice.call(list);`  `for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { console.log(arr[i].value);}`

Comment: unfortunately yes I do, the receiving page with a $_POST is already 100% working , will study your code further and see if I can further add what you have just posted on the comment, again thanks for your big help!

Comment: For a beginner you're doing exceedingly well. If you need anymore help on the front-end side of things (JS/jQ, HTML, and CSS), I'll be happy to help. Once concerns are back-end, (server-side), it'll be out of my realm of knowledge. Happy coding.:)